# How to read all http requests in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want my Chrome Extension to read and display all http requests in alerts. But alerts are not displaying, console is clear with no errors. Here is my code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function(details) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(details));
},
{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
["blocking", "requestBody"]
);
```

Also my manifest:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Some_Name",
"version": "1.2",

"content_scripts": [{"matches": ["<all_urls>","http://*/*", "https://*/*"],"js": ["background.js"]}],
"background": {

  "page": "background.html"
},

  "permissions": [
  "alarms",
  "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
],

    "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Some extension"
  },

  "icons": {
   "128": "icon.png" }

  }
```

Comment: What does it actually do?  _"Doesn't work"_ isn't much help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @FrankerZ, thanks, edited.